# How do I access some data of a property I passed from parent component to child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React and I am trying to call a function in a child component, that accesses a property that was passed from parent component and display it.

The props receives a "todo" object that has 2 properties, one of them is text.

I have tried to display the text directly without a function, like {this.props.todo.text} but it does not appear. I also tried like the code shows, by calling a function that returns the text.

This is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import "./App.css";
import TodoList from "./components/todoList";
import TodoElement from "./components/todoElement";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: []
    };
    this.addNewTodo = this.addNewTodo.bind(this);
  }

  addNewTodo(input) {
    const newTodo = {
      text: input,
      done: false
    };
    const todos = [...this.state.todos];
    todos.push(newTodo);
    this.setState({ todos });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <input type="text" id="text" />
        <button
          onClick={() => this.addNewTodo(document.getElementById("text"))}
        >
          Add new
        </button>

        {this.state.todos.map(todo => (
          <TodoElement key={todo.text} todo={todo} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is my todoElement.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class TodoElement extends Component {
  state = {};

  writeText() {
    const texto = this.props.todo.text;
    return texto;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <p id={this.writeText()>{this.writeText()}</p>
        <button>x</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TodoElement;
```

I expect that when I write in the input box, and press add, it will display the text.

Comment: what you are expecting by this line: `this.addNewTodo(document.getElementById("text"))`, value of text field? because it will return the input element not the input element value.

Comment: Read about the [`Ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to avoid `document.getElementById("text")` approach.

Comment: yes, I already debugged and it does what I expect it to in that part. It triggers the function addNewTodo, and passes in the argument, that is the text that was written in the input

Comment: @ArupRakshit what do you mean to read about the ref?

Comment: @Max, i think you are getting confused in that part, it will never return the value entered in input element, it will always return the input element (dom element). also avoid using that, either use refs or store the value in state variable. check [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) for getElementById.

Comment: on possible solution to your problem is, add `.value` with it: `this.addNewTodo(document.getElementById("text").value)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

> Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method.

I'll write it as:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: []
    };
    this.textRef = React.createRef();
    this.addNewTodo = this.addNewTodo.bind(this);
  }

  addNewTodo() {
    const newTodo = {
      text: this.textRef.current.value,
      done: false
    };
    const todos = [...this.state.todos, newTodo];
    this.setState({ todos });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input type="text" id="text" ref={this.textRef} />
        <button onClick={this.addNewTodo}>Add new</button>

        {this.state.todos.map(todo => (
          <TodoElement key={todo.text} todo={todo} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In your approach, what you got as an argument to the parameter `input` of the method `addNewTodo` is an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) object. It is not the value you entered into the text field. To get the value, you need to call `input.value`. But this is approach is not we encourage in React, rather we use `Ref` when need to access the html native dom.